# Event onClick with React

Tags: events, reactjs, onclick, components

I fool around with Reactjs and try launch this code

```
var Kaka = React.createClass({render() { return <div> Hell o forld </div> }})
var Application = React.createClass({
    handle() {console.log("took took");},
    render() {return <div><Kaka onClick = {this.handle} /></div>}
})
React.render(<Application  />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

[Example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/ogurchik/pen/wzKzrL?editors=1011#0)
I disire that while click on component Kaka starting work function "handle" and this return consol.log. But it doesn't work. 
My question is that, may an inner component use function which is function of  external component? On my example  an external component is Application, an inner component is Kaka, and a function which i want launch is handle.

Please, tell me why my snippet cod don't work. I think, i do not understand how a components interact between ourself. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `{this.handle}` as a property named `onClick` to the `KaKa` class - not actually adding a click handler to it.

You need to use this prop you are passing, something like this:

```
var Kaka = React.createClass({
   render() { 
     return <div onClick={this.props.onClick}> Hell o forld </div> }})
   }
});
```

[Here's a functional codepen of this](https://codepen.io/kiresuah/pen/EgVgzR?editors=1011).

Comment: Ho, it works! This "this.props.onClick" is props component Application?

Comment: When you specify something "on" a JSX element like `<KaKa name="Ogurchik" />`, the `KaKa` class receives it in a `props` object - so `this.props.name` would equal "Ogurchik". `this` refers to the instance of the class, `props` is the properties object in that class, and `name` is a field in the `props` object.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a prop called `onClick` to Kaka and then in Kaka, you are not calling that function anywhere... in Kaka change :

```
<div> Hell o forld </div>
```

to

```
<div onClick={this.props.onCLick}> Hell o forld </div>
```

then you should achieve the desired results